# How to reverse comparator order using stream API?

Tags: string, collections, java-8, java-stream, comparator

```
String obtained = transactions.stream()
    .map(Transaction::getTrader)
    .map(Trader::getName)
    .sorted(String::compareTo)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

What should I do if I want to reverse the natural alphabetical ordering in the returned string without writing a specific `Comparator<String>`, so that the concatenated string result starts with the names 'z..', 'y..', 'x..' and so on?

Answer (score 2):

In java, something like this can do the trick :

```
String obtained = transactions.stream()
                  .map(Transaction::getTrader).map(Trader::getName)
                  .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Note that it works because String implements Comparable Interface.

Comment: That is what i was expecting! Thx, TDRS

Comment: I think you meant `Comparator.reverseOrder()` instead of `Collection`

Answer (score 2):

Only one operation is required to sort collection in reversed order.

String implements Comparable interface. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) for *java.lang.Comparable#compareTo()* says that it returns:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object
>            is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object

To reverse order of collection you can:

1. **[recommended]** use *Comparator.reverseOrder* ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--)) which

   > Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse ordering of the
   >   specified comparator. (...)

   ```
   List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a","b","d", "c", "e");
   reversedOrderedStrings = strings.stream()
                               .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                               .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
   ```
2. invert order of compared parameters

   ```
   reversedOrderedStrings = strings.stream()
                               .sorted((s1, s2) ->  s2.compareTo(s1))
                               .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
   ```
3. **[not recommended]** change the sign of compareTo() method. This is not recommended as it can cause numeric overflow for Integer.MIN_VALUE

   ```
   reversedOrderedStrings = strings.stream()
                               .sorted((s1, s2) -> -s1.compareTo(s2))
                               .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
   ```

Output for all is the same:

```
System.out.println(reversedOrderedStrings);
e,d,c,b,a
```

Comment: You are right but the question says to not write your own comparator. I acknowledge that your method is faster and must be used.

Comment: Yes, i know i can do that, i was looking Collection.reverseOrder() method.

Comment: I should have used "sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())" in my answer as described in [Reverse a comparator in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995559/reverse-a-comparator-in-java-8).

Comment: @Holger - corrected the answer. Thanks for remarks.