# Sort list with two specifications

Tags: java, comparator, case-insensitive, treeset

I would like to sort a `TreeSet` with two criteria.

`Collections.reverseOrder()` and `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`

I know that I can make it with single of them:

```
Set<String> set1 = new TreeSet<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
Set<String> set2 = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

How should I implement a comparator to get this two criteria in one tree set?

```
Set<String> ser3 = new TreeSet<>(/* here comparator */);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a comparator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995559/reverse-a-comparator-in-java-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reverse the `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` comparator:

```
Set<String> caseInsensitiveStrings =
    new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.reversed());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> caseInsensitiveStrings = new TreeSet<String>(new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        if(o1.equalsIgnoreCase(o2)){
            return 0;
        }else if(o1.compareTo(o2)== 1){
             return -1;
        }else if(o1.compareTo(o2)== -1){ 
             return 1;
        } 
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
 });
```