# Collection.reverse() method not working on an Integer ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

the Collection.reverse() method in java doesn't seem to work with the Integer type array list I made.

```
    List<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mylist.add(33);
    mylist.add(304);
    mylist.add(25);
    mylist.add(67);

    Collections.reverse(mylist);

    System.out.println(mylist);
```

The actual output is: [67, 25, 304, 33]

I expected the output to be 304,67,33,25

Comment: Probably want `reverseOrder` - `reverse` simply reverses the positioning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a comparator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995559/reverse-a-comparator-in-java-8)

Answer (score 1):

`reverse` simply reverses the positioning - looks like you want to sort by its natural ordering in reverse so use `Collections.sort` with the convenience method of `Collections.reverseOrder` to produce the reverse comparator:

```
    List<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mylist.add(33);
    mylist.add(304);
    mylist.add(25);
    mylist.add(67);

    System.out.println("Before                  : "+mylist);

    Collections.reverse(mylist);
    System.out.println("Positional reverse      : "+mylist);        

    // start with original ordering
    mylist.clear();
    mylist.add(33);
    mylist.add(304);
    mylist.add(25);
    mylist.add(67);
    
    Collections.sort(mylist, Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println("Natural ordering reverse: "+mylist);
```

Produces:

```
Before                  : [33, 304, 25, 67]
Positional reverse      : [67, 25, 304, 33]
Natural ordering reverse: [304, 67, 33, 25]
```

Comment: Or just `mylist.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());`