# How to apply comparator to get the TOP 5 cities from a List sorted by population?

Tags: java, list, algorithm, comparator, observer-pattern

I have a ***class*** `City`

```
public final class City {
private final String name;
private final String state;
private final int    population;

public City(String name, String state, int population) {
    this.name       = name;
    this.state      = state;
    this.population = population;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public int getPopulation() {
    return population;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "City [name=" + name + ", state=" + state + ", population=" + population + "]";
}
}
```

And a class that implements `Observable` (not needed for this). This observable class holds an arraylist `List<City> cityList` that has the data for all the ***cities*** that have been reported.

My class `TopFiveCities` is supposed to:

> "implement a getter method getTopFive() returning a list with the five
> top cities (in terms of population) received. The list is sorted from
> higher to lower numbers. The returned list must be a copy of the list
> kept by the observer"

Aside from just getting the top 5 list, I also need to know how to make a ***copy*** of that *list* from the *observer*.

This is what I have:

```
public class TopFiveCities
implements Observer {

// THIS ALSO DOESN'T WORK UNLESS THE LIST IS STATIC
// SO HOW CAN I MAKE A COPY OF THE LIST FROM OBSERVER?
private List<City> list = new ArrayList<>(CensusOffice.cityList);

public List<City> getTopFive() {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<City>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(City o1, City o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.getPopulation(), o2.getPopulation());
        }
        
    });
    return list;
}

public void update(Observable observable) {
    if (!(observable instanceof Observable)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
}
```

With this, when one of the sample **outputs should** be:

```
City [name=Chicago, state=IL, population=2746388]
```

I just receive a list of **all** the cities, sorted by population from *LOWEST* to *HIGHEST*. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you specify that you only want 5 things?

Comment: @AndyTurner in the code I don't because I don't understand how to do that. But the list may also have less than 5 things (like my example output where it should just be the one city)

Comment: As I remember compare gets -1, 0, 1 values if you want to sort it highest to lowest then you can change compartor. Also you can get top 5 from the list

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez  okay, but How do you change it? / how do I get the top 5?

Comment: Simplest way is list.sublist(list.length - 5, list.length)

Comment: Okay that seems easy enough, so that just leaves making a copy of the list held by the observer (without that list being static), and changing the comparator @Gurkanİlleez

Comment: If you need to reverse it Collections.reverse can be used

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I tried that, it doesn't work because I still need to use Collections.sort() to be able to make it sorted by the population

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez it's better to use a reversed comparator than to reverse the list after sorting it.

Comment: Sure you are right

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995559/reverse-a-comparator-in-java-8

Comment: I don't really thing that can work too well but MAYBE if I knew how to copy that list from the observer so I could actually test it.

Comment: You don’t need `Collections` utility class.  `List` offers a `sort` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a Stream, use a Comparator to sort the stream, limit the number of element and convert the elements to a new list:

```
List<City> top5citiesByPopulation = cities.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(City::getPopulation).reversed())
        .limit(5)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Streams are likely not appropriate to this apparent schoolwork assignment.

Comment: @BasilBourque And this problem also doesn't require sorting.

Answer (score 0):

```
int order = requestedOrder.equals("asc") ? 1 : -1;

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<CustomObj>() {
    public int compare(CustomObj first, CustomObj scnd) {
        return first.getComparableParam().compareTo(scnd.getComparableParam()) * order;
    }
});
```

I just copied and passed this code block from recommended stackover page in the comment. Of you want ascending order simply change it. In your code order will be -1.

Simply you need to multiply by -1.

```
return Integer.compare(o1.getPopulation(), o2.getPopulation()) * -1;
```

After this you can sublist it.

You keep the list as global variable it can be reached from update method but it does not change if class is singleton except for update method. Your update method can change it by notifying

In update method you can simply clear and add new list by list.addAll

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a schoolwork assignment, I’ll describe the pieces but let you assemble them into final code.

> I have a class "City"

You could more briefly define that class as a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
City ( String name, String state, int population ) {}
```

> holds an array list "List cityList"

```
List < City > cities = new ArrayList<>();
```

> getting the top 5 list

[Sort the list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Java%20sort%20list%20by%20property) by [using a reverse comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32995559/642706). You can make a comparator for sorting by using a method reference for the accessor “getter” method. But be aware that records do not use the word “get” by default as their accessor, they use simply the name of the property.

```
cities.sort( Comparator.comparing( City :: population ).reversed() ) ;
```

For an unmodifiable list, call `List.of` or `List.copyOf`.

[`List#subset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) gives you a list with some of the elements of the original. But beware: the resulting list is based on a view of the original list. The subset is not separate and independent. To get a separate list, pass to `List.copyOf` or pass to the constructor of another `List` implementation.

```
List< City > topFivePop = List.copyOf( subset ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't require sorting the whole given list, which will have a time complexity of **O(n log n)**.

Basically, the task is somewhat similar to finding the maximum element in the list that can be done in **O(n)** time with a single pass through the given list.

The most suitable approach for this problem is a **partial sorting**, and the  best performance that could be achieved is the middle-ground between **O(n)** and **O(n log n)**.

In order to find `5` *maximum elements* in a list, we can maintain a *collection* that will store in **sorted order** up to `5` previously encountered *elements* with maximum values.

*Elements* that are lover than the *smallest element* in the *collection* will be discarded automatically if the *collection* is already of size `5`. Only new elements with a value higher than the *smallest element*'s value will trigger reordering of this tiny *collection*. I.e. the data will be sorted partially instead of sorting the whole data set.

In the implementation below for as *collection* that will store `5` max elements, I've chosen a `PriorityQueue`.

According to the [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) it's methods have the following *time complexity*.

> this implementation provides **O(log(n))** time for the *enqueuing* and *dequeuing* methods (**offer**, **poll**, **remove()** and **add**); linear time for the remove(Object) and contains(Object) methods; and **constant time** for the *retrieval* methods (**peek**, **element**, and **size**).

I.e. *adding* of a new element and *removing* the first element both will perform in logarithmic time, and accessing the smallest value in the queue with the method `element()` with done in **O(1)** time (*almost immediately*).

The `PriorityQueue` is encapsulated inside a generic ***class***, which *constructor* expects as parameters a `Comparator<T>` and a desired maximum size of the queue (*i.e. a number of max elements that needs to be found*).

The queue itself doesn't exposed to the outside classes. Method `addItem()` processing the given element and `getFirstN` returns a sorted immutable list.

`Comparator` in the code below is implemented using the static method `comparingInt()`. You could also implement `Comparator` in a *"classical way"* (pre-Java 8) by providing the behavior for it's abstract method `compare()` either by using a *lambda expression* or within an *anonymous inner class*.

```
public class FirstN<T> {
    private final Queue<T> queue;
    private final Comparator<T> comparator;
    private final int capacity;

    public FirstN(Comparator<T> comparator, int capacity) {
        this.queue = new PriorityQueue<>(comparator);
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public boolean addItem(T item) {
        if (capacity == queue.size() && comparator.compare(item, queue.element()) <= 0) {
            return false; // queue is full and the given item is smaller than the lowerest element in the queue
        }

        if (capacity == queue.size() && comparator.compare(item, queue.element()) > 0) {
            queue.remove(); // removing the first element if it's smaller than the given item
        }
        return queue.add(item); // adding the given item
    }

    public List<T> getFirstN() {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(queue); // creating a list based on a queue
        result.sort(comparator);
        return List.copyOf(result); // making a copy of the list (returned list is immutable)
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<City> cities = List.of(
            new City("Austin", "Texas", 1028225),
            new City("Los Angeles", "California", 3985516),
            new City("San Diego", "California", 1429653),
            new City("Houston", "Texas", 2325353),
            new City("Phoenix", "Arizona", 1759943),
            new City("New York City", "New York", 8177025),
            new City("San Antonio", "Texas", 1598964),
            new City("Philadelphia", "Pennsylvania", 1585480),
            new City("San Diego", "California", 1429653),
            new City("Chicago", "Illinois", 2671635),
            new City("Dallas", "Texas", 1348886));

    FirstN<City> top5Cities =
            new FirstN<>(Comparator.comparingInt(City::getPopulation), 5);

    for (City next: cities) {
        top5Cities.addItem(next);
    }

    List<City> result = top5Cities.getFirstN(); // contains 5 biggest US cities

    result.forEach(System.out::println); // printing the result
}
```

**Output** (order from lowest to highest)

```
City [name=Phoenix, state=Arizona, population=1759943]
City [name=Houston, state=Texas, population=2325353]
City [name=Chicago, state=Illinois, population=2671635]
City [name=Los Angeles, state=California, population=3985516]
City [name=New York City, state=New York, population=8177025]
```